# Need help on this for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

For my Java  practice midterm, we need to write the exact output of a line of code, in this case, a for loop. Here's the code:

```
for(int first = 3; first > 0; first--)
        for(int second = --first; second <= 5; second++)
            System.out.println(first + " " + second);
```

So I figured the output to be:

```
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
```

But when I run it in Ecplipse it comes out with:

```
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
```

I understand how "second" would go from 5 to 0 because of "second <= 5" but I don't see how "first" also resets to 0.

I searched all over for an answer, but couldn't find one. Any help on how this works would be great. Thanks!

Comment: use the debugger in eclipse. you'll see how the value of first changes

Comment: Also, note the `first--` and the `--first` in the code.

Comment: It's not the `second <= 5` that makes `second` go to zero - it's the `int second = --first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're decrementing `first` twice: once each time the outer loop iterates, and once each time the inner loop *starts* iterating.

So after printing `2 5` it hits the end of the inner loop, and hits the `first--` from the outer loop. Then as it goes back into the inner loop again, it hits `int second = --first` before printing anything else. Hence going from 2 to 0.

Personally I would try to avoid statements like `int second = --first;` - the side-effects often cause confusion.